# Возможна ли сейчас автоматизированная выгрузка фотографий/постов в Instagram через их новое GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook-api, instagram-api

Всем добрый день!

Читаю сейчас про АПИ инстаграма, о их связи с Facebook.

Я так и не могу понять пока главное - возможна ли вообще сейчас (не используя старое АПИ если оно вообще до сих пор еще работает) нормальная выгрузка в Instagram наших фотографий (с нашего сайта). Т.е. стоит ли вообще планировать такой функционал на своем сайте?

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, как Ваш текст "Одним словом - жесть." улучшает вопрос, вносит в него ясность?

Comment: Этот комментарий говорит о том, что сейчас Instagram и Facebook стали тесно связаны, и это вносит непонимание. Мне вот, например, пока так и не понятно в документации по Graph API что относится к Instagram, а что к Facebook. Из документации Instagram есть переход на документацию Graph API для instagram-media, и непонятно пока, как другие методы (а в них нет префикса instagra-) относятся именно к Instagram.